# No key or value or label error in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd version 2.10.4

And my code goes like this (basically on clicking the button a modal window is opened)

```
 <div className="storage-analysis clearfix">
          <span className="new-dash-btn">
            <Button   onClick ={this.NewAnalysisPopUp} style ={{"width":140,"height":40}}>New Analysis</Button>
          <Modal
            key="1"
            value="2"
            label="3"
            title="New Analysis" 
            visible={this.state.openModalDB}
            onOk={this.saveAndClose}
            onCancel={this.closeModal}
          >
            <div className="row to-margin-bottom">
              <div className="row modal-window-antd">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                      <label>Analysis Name
                      </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-8">
                  <AutoComplete
                    style={{ "width":"100%" }}
                    dataSource={analysisList}
                    onSelect={this.onSelect}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    placeholder="input here"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row modal-window-antd">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                      <label>Dashboard Name
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                      <Select
                        multi={true}
                        name="form-field-name"
                        value={this.state.dashboardSelected}
                        options={dashboardList}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeDashboard}
                      />
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </span>
                </div>
```

but on clicking the button element I am getting the following error:
Uncaught Error: no key or value or label(only for OptGroup) for [object Object]

Comment: Can you show the `NewAnalysisPopUp()` function as well?

Comment: Please, show what `dashboardList` contains

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Mine was a situation I need to chain two dispatch, but the first has to update the App's state before the other was allowed to dispatch.  I had a modal, than could initiate a call action to open another modal after to dispatches an action to close self

This caused above error

```
openOtherModal: () => {
    dispatch(actions.closeThisModal())
    dispatch(actions.openOtherModal())
  },
})
```

Using promise resolve... then() . solved the error

```
openOtherModal: () => {
      new Promise((resolve) => resolve(dispatch(actions.closeThisModal())))
        .then(() => {
            dispatch(actions.openOtherModal())
        });
  },
})
```